# Using dapper with stored procs to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using dapper I have some code that would have worked with a select statement but i am trying to convert it to using a stored proc the dapper documenation is a little sparse on async methods. So I am trying my best here.

```
public async Task<ActivityHeader> GetAllActivityHeader()
{
     Task<ActivityHeader> _activityHeader= new List<ActivityHeader>();
     using (IDbConnection conn = Connection)
     {
         if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
          conn.Open();
          _activityHeader = await conn.Query<ActivityHeader>("GetActivityHeader").ToList();
      }
      commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            return _activityHeader.Result() ;
        }
    }
```

How do i make this method Async comptable for a view and also what must I do on the view end to enable that ability as well ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dapper part is needed to be like this

```
public async Task<ActivityHeader> GetAllActivityHeader(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
      ....
      if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
           await conn.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);

      var activityHeaderTask = conn.QueryAsync<ActivityHeader>("GetActivityHeader", cancellationToken);
      var result = await activityHeaderTask.AsList()

      return result;
}
```

please note that using sections are not included. Also, `conn.Open()` is needed to bu `await conn.OpenAsync(cancellationToken)`